# Wrong camera movement and wrong rendering result using the framebuffer - LearnOpenGL

Tags: c++, glfw, framebuffer

I wonder if you can help me...
I followed learnopengl.com and learned the details about framebuffer. However when I am creating my own scene I found that when I press key "W", the camera moves towards the right and front. What's more, the containers, planes and the camera directions all seemed to have problems when rendering.
The results are listed below:

The direction of the camera originally wrong and when pressing W it seems like it is moving towards the right and front direction.

[image]

The rendering result also seems to have problems.
[image]
[image]

After my tests I think the problem might be the mistakenly use of `glViewport`. When I set the glViewport(0,0,800,600) after binding the new framebuffer, I got the output like this:

[image]

You can see the distortion disappeared however I only got things rendered on the left bottom corner...

Below is the correct output:(https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers)
[image]

This is my source code:

```cpp
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "LearnOpenGL/camera.h"
#include "LearnOpenGL/stb_image.h"
#include "glad/glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <LearnOpenGL/filesystem.h>
#include <LearnOpenGL/model.h>
#include "imgui-1.89/imgui.h"


void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height);

void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos);

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xoffset, double yoffset);

unsigned int loadTexture(char const * path);
// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// camera attributes
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;
float fov = 45.0f;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f; // time between current frame and last frame
float lastFrame = 0.0f; // time of last frame



int main() {

    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "My Playground", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    Shader shader("../chapters/advanced_opengl/shaders_framebuffer/framebuffer.vert", "../chapters/advanced_opengl/shaders_framebuffer/framebuffer.frag");
    Shader screenShader("../chapters/advanced_opengl/shaders_framebuffer/framebuffer_screen.vert","../chapters/advanced_opengl/shaders_framebuffer/framebuffer_screen.frag");


    float cubeVertices[] = {
            // positions          // texture Coords
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,

            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,

            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    float planeVertices[] = {
            // positions          // texture Coords
            5.0f, -0.5f,  5.0f,  2.0f, 0.0f,
            -5.0f, -0.5f,  5.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            -5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f,  0.0f, 2.0f,

            5.0f, -0.5f,  5.0f,  2.0f, 0.0f,
            -5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f,  0.0f, 2.0f,
            5.0f, -0.5f, -5.0f,  2.0f, 2.0f
    };
    float quadVertices[] = { // vertex attributes for a quad that fills the entire screen in Normalized Device Coordinates.
            // positions   // texCoords
            -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,

            -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f
    };

    // cube VAO
    unsigned int cubeVAO, cubeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &cubeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &cubeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cubeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(cubeVertices), &cubeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    // plane VAO
    unsigned int planeVAO, planeVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &planeVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &planeVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, planeVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(planeVertices), &planeVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    // screen quad VAO
    unsigned int quadVAO, quadVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quadVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &quadVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quadVertices), &quadVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));

    unsigned int cubeTexture = loadTexture(FileSystem::getPath("resources/container.jpg").c_str());
    unsigned int floorTexture = loadTexture(FileSystem::getPath("resources/metal.png").c_str());

    // configuration
    shader.use();
    shader.setInt("texture1",0);
    screenShader.use();
    screenShader.setInt("screenTexture",0);

    unsigned int framebuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

    // create a color attachment texture
    unsigned int textureColorbuffer;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureColorbuffer);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer, 0);

    // create a renderbuffer object for depth and stencil attachment (we won't be sampling these)
    unsigned int rbo;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0); // once we've allocated enough memory for the renderbuffer object we can unbind the renderbuffer.
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo); // attach the renderbuffer object to the depth and stencil attachment of the framebuffer
    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)!=GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        std::cout<<"ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!"<<std::endl;
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0); // be sure to unbind the framebuffer to make sure we're not accidentally rendering to the wrong framebuffer.

    // draw as wireframe
    // glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);


    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = static_cast<float>(glfwGetTime());
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------

        // bind to framebuffer and draw scene as we normally would to color texture
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // enable depth testing (is disabled for rendering screen-space quad)


        // firstly clear the screen
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        shader.use();
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float) SCR_WIDTH / (float) SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f,100.0f);
        shader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        shader.setMat4("view", view);

        // cubes
        glBindVertexArray(cubeVAO);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model",model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
        model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        shader.setMat4("model", model);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        // floor
        glBindVertexArray(planeVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, floorTexture);
        shader.setMat4("model", glm::mat4(1.0f));
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        // now bind back to default framebuffer and draw a quad plane with the attached framebuffer color texture
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // disable depth test so screen-space quad isn't discarded due to depth test.

        // clear all relevant buffers
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // set clear color to white (not really necessary actually, since we won't be able to see behind the quad anyways)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        screenShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureColorbuffer); // use the color attachment texture as the texture of the quad plane
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }


    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int width, int height) {
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xpos, double ypos) {
    if (firstMouse) {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed: y ranges from bottom to top
    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow *window, double xoffset, double yoffset) {
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(static_cast<float>(yoffset));
}

unsigned int loadTexture(char const * path)
{
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char *data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    return textureID;
}
```

This is my framebuffer.vert:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

This is my framebuffer.frag:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(texture1, TexCoords);
}
```

This is my framebuffer_screen.vert:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoords;

out vec2 TexCoords;

void main()
{
    TexCoords = aTexCoords;
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

This is my framebuffer_screen.frag:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;

uniform sampler2D screenTexture;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture(screenTexture, TexCoords);
}
```

I tried to find the problem but I couldn't figure it out... I would appreciate it if you could help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the difference between width / height in raw pixels (i.e. number of physical pixels) v.s. width / height in screen coordinates (i.e. logical window size). There is a note on the [GLFW window guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window_guide.html) that says:

> Do not pass the window size to glViewport or other pixel-based OpenGL calls. The window size is in screen coordinates, not pixels. Use the framebuffer size, which is in pixels, for pixel-based calls.

[`glfwCreateWindow()` requires the width and height to be in screen coordinates](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3555a418df92ad53f917597fe2f64aeb). Therefore, the `SCR_WIDTH` and `SCR_HEIGHT` are in screen coordinates. All other places, however, require width and height in raw pixels, which can be obtained by either

1. saving the `width` and `height` values passed to your `framebuffer_size_callback` callback function, or
2. calling `glfwGetFramebufferSize` from your main function, which is easier.

Using the framebuffer size (instead of `SCR_WIDTH` and `SCR_HEIGHT`) to calculate all the rendering stuff for the `gl*` calls solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you! Calling `glfwGetFramebufferSize` and replacing SCR_WIDTH and SCR_HEIGHT with actual physical pixels size really worked. I will check those documentation websites for further information.